# Add plugin for WildFly Application Server to NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jboss, netbeans-plugins, wildfly

I am trying to add WildFly Server to NetBeans 8.0.

I go through the path: Tools -> Plugins -> Available plugins

Here is the screen shot: http://s29.postimg.org/8s8k6lck7/Wild_Fly.png

There are no results... So I can't add WildFly Server to use it in NetBeans. 
Maybe someone has ever had similar problem, what am I doing wrong? 
Please, help me!
Thanks.

Comment: Just checked and it didn't show up here either, though the following article says it should: http://blog.arungupta.me/2013/12/netbeans8-and-wildfly8-techtip-6/

Comment: @Puce yes, strange. I have tried to find something about WildFly and NetBeans 8 problems, but didn't manage to find anything similar :( Help me anyone!

Comment: I've added another comment to https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=234452 and  http://blog.arungupta.me/2013/12/netbeans8-and-wildfly8-techtip-6/

Comment: @Puce thank you, hope it may help.

Comment: @Puce I have managed to make plugin appear in the "available plugins" list.. But I have installed NetBeans Nightly version, there everything is good.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I added new comments to the issue and the article.

Comment: If anyone has issues with Wildfly, I spent a few hours on google trying to figure it out (Wildfly ver 8 with Netbeans ver 8), and its actually really simple; this plugin is not available but I do not think it is needed.  Instead go to tools - servers. add server, add WILDFLY server, don't say Jboss.  And then you can go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to make NetBeans find WildFly plugin.

I had NetBeans 8.0 on my machine installed. For now, if you need to use WildFly from NetBeans - the answer is to install the latest NetBeans Nightly build. I have installed the following JEE bundle: http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/

So, I have added WildFly and in NetBeans IDE Build 201404150001 it works:
http://s29.postimg.org/n3zi8k2qf/Wild_Fly.png

**UPDATE:** I've written about this in twitter, and guys fixed this! Now everything works fine in NetBeans 8.0. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the WildFly plugin without downloading an unstable NetBeans build.

[You can download the WildFly plugin directly from the NetBeans website](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/53333/wildfly-application-server) and install through the "Downloaded" tab in Tools -> Plugins

Comment: Thanks for solution Mike, it is much better than using Nightly NB version. For now this problem is fixed, and everyone can install WildFly from available plugins.